# How do I implement Google "Off the Record" with Smack API

Tags: xmpp, smack, google-talk

I have a functioning XMPP chat client that is working with gtalk.  I can not figure out how to implement some of the google custom extensions using the Smack API.

Specifically, I want to set the google talk user settings such that archivingenabled = false as described in the following link.

https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/usersettings

Additionally, if I decide to leave archivingenabled= true and try to control the google off the record setting individually I would need help monitoring and setting the google:nosave state as described in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/otr

My problem is that I can't figure out how to implement either of these things in code.  The igniteRealtime documentation describes the approach in the following link:

www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html
(note: http:// was removed because I was over my limit on links)

I would appreciate any examples on how to code these 2 google talk extensions.

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating a packet that extends [IQ](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/IQ.html) to send your requests.  This can then be sent using [SynchPacketSend()](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/util/SyncPacketSend.html).  Each individual command is an extension to be added to this IQ packet.

Then create a provider, as shown in the link you provided to convert the reply into your custom packet type.

You can look at the [LeafNode.getItems()](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/pubsub/LeafNode.java?r=11346&r=11346&r=11346&r=11456&r=11346&r=11613&r=11613&r=12303&r=12303&r=11613&r=11613) request as an example.  Just follow the code and it will show you how to create and send the appropriate IQ packet.  Check the providers package for how to receive replies.